# Retrofit. Приложение спамит запросы с @Multipart файлом

Tags: android, retrofit, rest, retrofit2

Добрый день,

Без особой надежды решил спросить у комрадов загадочный баг на продакшене в(из специфики возможен слабый и ненадежный интернет в районе).

Редко при отправке файла на сервер приходит до сотен повторяющихся запросов от одного пользователя. промежуток между запросами иногда не более одной миллисекунды(что долго наталкивало на мысль о проблеме со стороны сервера). В условиях дева и QA бага не репродюсится.

Это сам API:

```
Api{
     @Multipart
     @POST("data/behaviour/{deviceId}/{sessionId}")
     Call<ResponseBody> sendBehaviourInApp(@Path("deviceId") String 
     deviceId,@Path("sessionId") String sessionId,
                                         @Part("file\"; 
     filename=\"data.txt\" ")RequestBody behavoirFile);
```

это отправка файла(не относящиеся к делу места были подчищены):

```
public void send(Context context, RetrofitController controller, File behaviour){
      Api api = controller.createInterface(Api.class, context);
      RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("plain/text"), behaviour);
      Call<ResponseBody> call = api.sendBehaviourInApp(              
      NetworkManager.requestDeviceId(context), data.getId(),
                fbody);
            call.enqueue(new BehaviorRestroCallback<ResponseBody>(context))
    }
```

и создание самого интерфейса:

```
public class RetrofitController {
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    private Retrofit.Builder builder;
    private String serverURL;

    public RetrofitController(String serverURL) {
           this.serverURL = serverURL;
           builder =  new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(serverURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    }

private Retrofit.Builder getBuilder() {
    if (builder == null) {
        builder =
                new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(serverURL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    }
    return builder;
}

 public <S> S createInterface(Class<S> serviceClass, Context context) {
       initParameters(context);
       Retrofit retrofit = getBuilder().client(httpClient.readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
 }

   private void initParameters(final Context context) {
         if(!inited) {
             cinited = true;
             //get system parameters
             String versionName = "1";
             try {
                 PackageInfo pInfo = 
  context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            versionName = versionToDouble(pInfo.versionName);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String version = versionName;
        final String platform = "android";// + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        // add interceptor
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                    requestBuilder.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                requestBuilder.addHeader("platform", platform);
                requestBuilder.addHeader("clientVersion", version);
                requestBuilder.addHeader("deviceId", NetworkManager.requestDeviceId(context));
                requestBuilder.addHeader("sessionId", FidoApplication.getInstance().getModel().getSessionState().getSessionId());
                return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
            }
        });
    }
```

}

BehaviorRestroCallback не прикладываю так как время обработки Response не заняло бы миллисекунду. Могу только сказать что при различных условиях класс выполнит метод send(context,controller, behaviour) повторно(возможно в другом потоке).

Вариант который приходит в голову это асинхронная отправка одновременно двух и более подобных запросов, но если бы даже два запроса отправляли один и тот же файл(и как-то обошли все проверки) результатом бы стала отправка null вместо файла, но файл спамящийся на сервере имеет нормальный размер.

Возможно влияет создание двух интерфейсов через один билдер.

лог этого файла на сервере начинается обычно так(сразу же файл этого размера спамит без задержек)

```
2017-07-20 09:49:29.353000  "c.f.m.s.MapiWebRequestTraceFilter - Accepted 
request: {method=POST, 
path=/mapi/v2/data/behaviour/357103074752073/1500544032714, headers={content-
length=641, platform=android, clientversion=2.69, sessionid=1500544032714, 
content-type=multipart/form-data; accept-encoding=gzip, user-
agent=okhttp/3.3.0}}"
2017-07-20 09:49:29.391000  "c.f.m.s.MapiWebRequestTraceFilter - Accepted 
request: {method=POST, 
path=/mapi/v2/data/behaviour/357103074752073/1500544032714, headers={content-
length=641, platform=android, clientversion=2.69, sessionid=1500544032714, 
content-type=multipart/form-data; accept-encoding=gzip, user-
agent=okhttp/3.3.0}}"

  2017-07-20 09:49:29.392000    "c.f.m.s.MapiWebRequestTraceFilter - Accepted 
  request:  {method=POST, 
path=/mapi/v2/data/behaviour/357103074752073/1500544032714, headers=
{content-length=641, platform=android, clientversion=2.69, 
sessionid=1500544032714, content-type=multipart/form-data; accept-
encoding=gzip, user-agent=okhttp/3.3.0}}"
2017-07-20 09:49:29.393000  "c.f.m.s.MapiWebRequestTraceFilter - Accepted 
request:  {method=POST, 
path=/mapi/v2/data/behaviour/357103074752073/1500544032714, headers=
{content-length=641, platform=android, clientversion=2.69, 
sessionid=1500544032714, content-type=multipart/form-data; accept-
encoding=gzip, user-agent=okhttp/3.3.0}}"
2017-07-20 09:49:29.393000  "c.f.m.s.MapiWebRequestTraceFilter - Accepted 
request:  {method=POST, 
path=/mapi/v2/data/behaviour/357103074752073/1500544032714, headers=
{content-length=641, platform=android, clientversion=2.69, 
sessionid=1500544032714, content-type=multipart/form-data; accept-
encoding=gzip, user-agent=okhttp/3.3.0}}"
2017-07-20 09:49:29.393000  "c.f.m.s.MapiWebRequestTraceFilter - Accepted 
request:  {method=POST, 
path=/mapi/v2/data/behaviour/357103074752073/1500544032714, headers=
{content-length=641, platform=android, clientversion=2.69, 
sessionid=1500544032714, content-type=multipart/form-data; accept-
encoding=gzip, user-agent=okhttp/3.3.0}}"
```

Comment: Константа TIMEOUT ввиду других причин была установлена в 120 секунд, что в сравнении с обычными 15 секундами просто неоправданно большой задел. Отправка файла тоже ограничена 3 попытками. Всегда есть возможность того, что где-то там может быть ошибка но как это обьясняет что несколько десятков и то и сотня запросов пришли за один раз с промежутком в 1 миллисекунду?   а Как можно отключить повтор запроса?

Comment: например, через `okhttpClient.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(false)`

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, хотя боюсь что на продакшене нам эксперементировать не дадут даже с небольшим процентом релизов